# How to reference a Java object again after changing the original reference variable

Tags: java, variables, object, memory, reference

I thought that this would be a good exercise for understanding a bit more about objects.

I'm trying to figure out how to reference an object again after changing the object's original reference variable.

Take the following code:

```
String person = "person a"; //Line 1
person = "person b";        //Line 2
```

Now, line 1 creates a new String object with the reference variable being `person`. Line 2 assigns that reference variable to another new String object. The original String object now has no reference variable.

How would I circle back and reference the original String object that is already in memory on line 1? Say, assigning the reference variable `person` back to the original String object? As a subsequent thought (not that I know that much about garbage collection), but is the original object eligible for garbage collection being that it does not have a reference variable anymore after line 2, and is therefore ineligible to be referenced again?

I am seeing the `hashCode()` method, and also the `System.identityHashCode()` but can't figure out how to implement it all in order to reference the original object again.

Comment: You can't. Store the previous value in a temporary variable and access it through that.

Comment: `hashCode()` (and `System.identityHashCode()`) are not for retrieving a specific object; its value cannot be interpreted as a memory address. The hash code is for determining whether two objects are definitely *not* equal.

Comment: @AndyTurner so if two objects have the same `hash code`, we can't say they have the same memory address ?

Comment: @Shashwat `String a = "hello"; String b = new String("hello"); System.out.println(a == b); System.out.println(a.hashCode() == b.hashCode());`.

Comment: I'd say `hashCode` is more for creating an integer representation of an object. Which is used for hash tables for instance, where uniqueness of the hash code, is a plus, and using the memory address gives a good level of uniqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 3: `person = "person a";` Java has a `String` intern cache. Now if it wasn't a `String` (or some other cached type), the answer would be you don't. Because the referecned object was eligible for garbage collection (it has no references anymore). You can validate this like,

```
String person = "person a"; //Line 1
System.out.println(person.hashCode());
person = "person b";        //Line 2
person = "person a";        //Line 3
System.out.println(person.hashCode());
```

which will display the same hashCode twice; because it's the same instance.

Comment: So, if a String equals a previously created String object, it will just use the original object, but with most other objects you simply lose the ability to use them again once they do not have a reference variable anymore (or no reference variable in the first place)?

Comment: But it's important to note that `"Aa"` and `"BB"` have the same hashcode; but they are different objects. (And, of course, `"Aa"` and `new String("Aa")` have the same hashcode, but they are different objects too). Hash code can't be used to "locate" a particular object.

Answer (score 0):

After you assign the new String

```
person = "person b";
```

The first one vanishes..
You won't be able to use it because you have lost his address.